# Unit testing controller action which redirects to another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd

I am following TDD approach to develop my MVC website. I have a `PaymentController` which is going to have an action method `MakePayment` which I am testing using a test method as given below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MakePaymentLoad()
{
    PaymentController payController = new PaymentController();
    ViewResult payResult = payController.MakePayment() as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(payResult);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MakePaymentResult()
{
    PaymentController payController = new PaymentController();
    Payment payment = new Payment {
        BillerId = 1,
        PayAmt = 1.0,                
        PayDt = DateTime.Now,
        ConfCode = null,
        BillAccount = "123",
        PayStatus = 1,
        FeeStatus = 1,
        Platform =1
    };
    ViewResult payResult = payController.MakePayment(payment) as ViewResult;
    PaymentResult result = payResult.Model as PaymentResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result.ConfCode);            
}
```

In the above given test methods `MakePaymentLoad` only checks if the view is rendered and `MakePaymentResult` checks out if the confirmation code is present in the view model.

My action methods are given below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakePayment(Payment payment)
{
    PaymentResult payResult = new PaymentResult {
        ConfCode = "123"
    };
    if (true)
    {
        TempData["ConfCode"] = "123";
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
    }
    return View(payment);
}

public ViewResult MakePayment()
{            
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Confirmation()
{
    PaymentResult result = new PaymentResult {
        ConfCode = Convert.ToString(TempData["ConfCode"])
    };
    return View(result);
}
```

The `MakePaymentLoad` passes as it only check if the view is rendered whereas `MakePaymentResult` fails miserably as the result of action method is null because of the use `RedirectToAcion` inside `MakePayment's` post version. Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: is `if (true)` intentional? if it is always going to go there then there is no need for the conditional and also the view

Comment: I am following TDD approach. Initially we need to make the unit test case pass with bare minimum code. The code is refactored afterwards.

Comment: I understand TDD approach. But what do you want to test. the redirect of the view? because the action will always redirect with the current code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am going to call web service which will return me ConfCode and I will replace the if(true) condition with if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(confCode))

Answer (score 2):

you should test it like following

```
var payResult = (RedirectToActionResult)payController.MakePayment(payment)

Assert.AreEqual("Confirmation", action.RouteValues["action"]);
```

As you are returning redirect result, you can't expect a model in return.

Comment: What if I want to check ConfCode?

Comment: refer this link https://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/mvc-unit-testing-controller-actions-that-use-tempdata